# How can I program my own financial indicator to be plotted in a TradingChart?

Tags: plotting, finance

`FinancialIndicator["ind", par1, par2, ...]` represents a financial indicator "ind" with parameters $par1$, $par2$, etc.

All available financial indicators can be displayed with `FinancialIndicator[]`.

Is it possible to program my own financial indicator and to plot it in a `TradingChart`? How can I do it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this as duplicate of [your new question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/231660/how-can-i-plot-my-financial-indicator-below-a-trading-chart-produced-by-trading/232823#232823) on the same topic. Next time, please edit the original question with more details instead of creating a new one. (If you edit the question, it will also be put back to the top of the list of questions, so the chances of the right people seeing your question should also be similar to asking a new question)

Comment: @ Lukas, I did not ask this question. When I try to ask a new question, I came across this question as a similar question. I would also vote to close it, though.